# How to run single scenario

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Everytime I'm trying to run a single feature file or a single scenario in a feature file, it create new configuration file in intellij. The `Glue` property is empty and the `Feature or folder path` is located on a specific feature file, the feature file of that scenario:

[image]

[image]

The errors after trying to run a single feature file or a single scenario is:

`Undefined step: ....` for every step in the feature file/scenario I'm trying to run.

**Is there any sulotion to this problem instead of creating 1000 configurations?**

---

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different versions of Cucumber involved. 1.2.4 and 1.2.5, is that the reason you're having problems?

Answer (score 0):

IDEA adds "glue" automatically if your step definition file is located under named package (not right under test->java).
I checked this example http://github.com/czeczotka/cucumber-jvm-maven with your dependencies and it seems to work fine.